# Clone text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to copy text from one part of my website to another. How would you mod this code to match my HTML?

jQuery :

```
$('caption span').each(function(index) {
    $(this).text($(this).closest('table').find('th').text());
});
```

---

HTML:

```
<span class="original">Clone This Text #1</span>
<span class="copy">Place New Text Here</span>
```

[image]

Comment: Why is this even tagged as PHP? If you want to show that line in different positions on the site, store it in a variable, and print it out where it needs to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jQuery's .text() function to get the text node from `<span class="original">` and to set the text node of `<span class="copy">` to the previous value. Read the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Use the following jQuery code:

```js
$('.copy').text($('.original').text());

$('button').click(function () {
  $('.copy-2').text($('.original-2').text());
});
```

```css
.copy {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Cloning of text is ran here on load</h3>
<span class="original">Clone This Text #1</span> <br>
<span class="copy">Place New Text Here</span>

<h3>Here, you can see it happen on button click</h3>
<span class="original-2">Clone This Text #2</span> <br>
<span class="copy-2">Place New Text Here</span>
<button>click</button>
```